# Mysql query with special characters?

Tags: mysql

I (newbie) have hard time to understand this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT q.*, IF(v.id,1,0) AS voted
FROM quotes AS q
LEFT JOIN quotes_votes AS v 
ON  q.id = v.qid
    AND v.ip =".$ip."
    AND v.date_submit = '".$today."'
");
```

can anybody provide more info on what these short symbols like 'q.*' with the if statement and v.id,1,0. Any sources to read more about this?

Thank you very much.

this is how the tables looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `quotes` (
      `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `txt` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
      `author` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
      `bgc` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
      `votes` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `vsum` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `rating` double NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      KEY `rating` (`rating`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

CREATE TABLE `quotes_votes` (
  `id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `qid` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ip` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `vote` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date_submit` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `dt_submit` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `qid` (`qid`,`ip`,`date_submit`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: MySQL documentation might be helpful for you - read up on table/column aliases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `select q.*`, it just means getting all fields from the table alias `q`, which happens to be table `quotes`. It is like `select *` but just for one table.

Regarding `IF(v.id,1,0)`, that is really a *MySQLism*. The `IF` statement evaluates an expression given in the first argument and, if it is `true`, returns the second argument. Otherwise it returns the third argument. So you know that a `1` or a `0` will come out of the `IF`. You might now be wondering how can `v.id` be evaluated to return a logical value and the reason behind it is that MySQL treats booleans as if they were `TINYINT(1)` in which `0` is considered as `false` and non-zero values are considered as `true`.

So that would be rephrased into `IF(v.id != 0, 1, 0)` which might be easier to read. Given the fact that `v.id` can not be null then you could rewrite that this way `IF(v.id = 0, 0, 1)`. Anyway, you could take a step further and just replace it with `v.id != 0` :)